# prevent url tampering in php

Tags: php, url, tampering

This is a test engine application with 5 papers set by me..as 5 php pages

Flow of the application

Login.html

check.php // to check whether credentials r right

if correct then

main.php  //user clicks on "take test" in this page which displays him 1 of the 5 papers...

but once i am logged in i can just change the url to the url of the test paper i want..the paper names r 1.php 2.php....

how do i stop this...??

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['page'])//Tp
        continue;           //Tp
else
 {
   header('Location:login.php');
   exit;
 }                               //Tp
$_SESSION['page']=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];//tp
```

is this correct...as i said there are 5 pages....

in eac page i have this code....

i check whether the Session variable is set....if it is set...it means it already has visited the page.....but this code doesnt work...did i use the variable _SESSION['page']
before declaring it???

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: We have to build a secure application...i am done with the apllication...but not at all secure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems you're having could mostly be solved by arranging your code around a default handler script. (see my guidelines below.)

There are two basic ways to pass information to such a script (as I said in a comment above). The basic way is via a GET variable, like `http://www.example.com/main.php?p=1`.

If you want to have more visitor-friendly URLs, you can use a [`RewriteRule`](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite) in an `.htaccess` file to convert the nice URLs into the URLs that your handler will understand. (You'll need [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) enabled.)

This may be overkill for this particular question, but here are a few guidelines for secure web apps. I think they're all relevant:

1. Put your sensitive information **outside of the public web root**.
2. **By default, don't display any information**. Only enable the displaying of information if the user is positively authorized.
3. Ideally, this includes URLs (if they type in a valid URL but they're not authorized, don't let them know they've reached a valid URL). One way is to redirect (set the location header like you were doing) to the login page if they're not authorized.
4. **Create a default handler script.** This central script will include all needed files and call all the needed functions. Pass all request information to this handler, and have it output all the HTML.
5. Requirement for #3: **Encapsulate your code** in functions and classes. That way, your default handler can call them when it's ready, only if you need them, and not simply because they happened to be included. This allows you much more control over the flow of your app.
6. Instead of `echo`ing HTML in random places throughout your code, **return all HTML output to your main handler**, which will collect it and output it all in one place when it's ready. Random `echo`s scattered around make it easier for security holes to crop up.
7. **Don't trust user input**. If you're going to use a value you get from `$_GET` or `$_POST`, make SURE it's a valid value before you use it.

---

**Edit:**

*(This is more specific and directed toward your code as it is right now)*

There are **3 reasons your code won't run as you expect it to:**

1. You left out a closing parenthesis on the first line `if(!isset($_SESSION['page'])`.
2. The way your code is written, if `$_SESSION['page']` is already set when the user visits the page, they will be redirected to the login page. You can fix this by putting the `header('Location:login.php');
   exit;` in the `if` clause and removing the `else` clause completely:

   ```
   if(!isset($_SESSION['page'])) {
      header('Location:login.php');
      exit;
   }
   $_SESSION['page']=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
   ```
3. You need to set `$_SESSION['page']` when they first log in so they will be able to view the first page.

I'd recommend using an integer for `$_SESSION['page']` instead of the script name. That way, you can set `$_SESSION['page']` to 1 when they log in, and each time they successfully view a page, increment `$_SESSION['page']` by one. Consider `$_SESSION['page']` to mean *the next paper this user is allowed to view*.

You can set a `$pageid` on each paper. Each time they try to view a page, if `$_SESSION['page']` is less than `$pageid`, don't let them view the page.

Comment: sry for the late reply....had an 8 hr class to attend...could u just give me a start as to how to create a central script handling all 5 papers....

Comment: actually....wht i meant was...if the session[page ] is not set...tht means the user is visiting the page for the the 1st time....if the user changes the url...then in tht page when the session variable is checked i.e session[page] ...which now..would already be set as user has already visited 1 page...hence it would redirect the user to login page....

Comment: in your code...when it checks tht session is not set it would redirect...but no chance was given for the session[page ] to set...hence it would always redirect..isnt it??

Comment: @willell it worked...i used integers and it works now.....thanx....1 last query...In your best practises checklist the 1st point.. could you elaborate....Then while accessing it...i would have to give the entire path right...from root???

Comment: @Vinod K -- That's right, you'd need to give the entire path. From root is the most direct way, e.g. `/var/www/mysite/check.php` in Linux or `C:\web\mysite\check.php` in Windows depending on where you put your scripts. Alternately, you can add your script directory to [include_path](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) in php.ini, but that's not necessary. Either way, you need to make sure the web server has enough permissions to read from that directory.

Comment: Hey, no problem. Glad I could help. I appreciate programming help too. Btw, the book [Practical PHP Programming](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp) is a handy reference. I learned PHP by reading through it. I hope your class goes well.

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to build true authentication and authorization into your application.  Then the URL that serves the paper needs to verify that the user is allowed to view the page before serving it.

Whatever you are doing in check.php, do it on the paper page itself.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of alternatives. A couple:

- Don't encode the name of the paper names in the URL but return the contents of the selected paper from a page called, say, test-paper.php.
- track the papers the user is entitled to see in the user's session. Check in each test paper page whether the user is allowed to see this one and return a 403 Forbidden (or an error page) if they're not.

Many more, I'm sure.

Comment: could u elaborate on the 1st option....like are u saying....before i send the pages 1.php 2.php....i need to convert them such tht the client would see the URL as /test-paper...how do i do tht??

Comment: Have code for test-paper.php that selects one of hte test papers for this user, then return the content of that paper as the page content. So every user loads test-paper.php, it's just that the content is different for differnet users.

Comment: 2 possible ways: 1. pass the requested page as a GET var, like example.com/main.php?p=1   or 2. use a RewriteRule in an .htaccess file. (mod_rewrite)

Comment: correction: The basic way is to pass the requested page as a GET var, like `example.com/main.php?p=1`  -- and if you want pretty URLs, you can use a `RewriteRule` in an `.htaccess` file to convert the pretty URL into the URL that contains the GET variable.